# Increase size of text area without using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following piece of HTML

```
<div class="cf section unifyRepeat" >
    <h2>Unmatched Accuracy, Unmatched Speed</h2>
    <div class="content">
        <p>blah blah blah...</p>
        <p>Not any more....</p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- .section -->
```

This produces an area of text. The text however only goes about 50 percent across the page before it goes to a new line. Is there a way that I can increase the width of the text so I can fit more on a line?

Comment: We're going to need a working example (with CSS) to help you. Your current example works as you're wanting.

Comment: This sounds like a browser-dependent question. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Don't know if this matters, but assumer there is a lot of text in the <p> 's More than I show

Comment: @EranZimmerman I am using safari, but it does it across all

Comment: @user489041, we need the full example to reproduce. This code does not reproduce the issue you're talking about.

Comment: remove _css tag_ if you don't want to use css.

Answer (score 2):

By default, a `<div>` will use all available width. No settings are required for that. If it's not doing so, then you already have CSS or other styling preventing this.

If you want help with your CSS/styling, then you'll need to provide it so folks can see it.

Comment: Im actually pretty new to html, Im not actually sure where the css is located? I could do a search on the project for it, I'm just not cut ally sure what to search for.

Comment: If you want to become very good at this, learn to use the tools in browsers such as Google Chrome (F12). It gives you the ability to select an element and then see where all the styles applied to that element are coming from. May be a little daunting if you're just getting started though.